# Oracle SQL - Alternative to the UNION ALL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Given the follownig query that uses a union,

```
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
from tableA
union all
Select a,b,c,d,e,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(tableB.children as clob_nt)) temp, col7
from tableB
```

i would expect to get the following output (i.e. rows from both tables)

```
tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.clob(x) tableA.x
tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.x tableA.clob(x) tableA.x
tableB.x tableA.x tableA.x tableB.x tableB.x tableB.clob(x) tableB.x
tableB.x tableA.x tableA.x tableB.x tableB.x tableB.clob(x) tableB.x
tableB.x tableA.x tableA.x tableB.x tableB.x tableB.clob(x) tableB.x
```

What other options are available that will allow me to run the query without using 'union' or 'union all' and get the same results

Comment: You are selecting two result lists and combine them to get one list. This is exacly what UNION [ALL] is made for. So why would you want to avoid UNION here? Sorry, I can think of no reason.

Comment: Presumably this is because of the behaviour you're seeing on your previous question? It would be better to figure that out; even if you could come up with a hack to avoid `union all`, it could suffer from the same issue. Making a reproducible test case as Justin suggested is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yes it is because for some reason the union all is nullifying the clob objects. I am trying to find a quick temporary patch for it while i try to figure out the permanent solution.

Comment: The DBA has suggested that it could be something to do with the way the Optimizer is configured and he wont be able to look into it straight away hence i am trying to work out a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can do this in Oracle, but the coding is a bit messy.  The idea is to do a `full outer join` on a non-matching field, and then use `coalesce()` to bring the results together:

```
select coalesce(a.col1, b.a) as col1,
       coalesce(a.col2, b.b) as col2,
       coalesce(a.col3, b.c) as col3,
       coalesce(a.col4, b.d) as col4,
       coalesce(a.col5, b.e) as col5,
       coalesce(cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)),
                cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(b.children as clob_nt))
               ) as temp,
       coalesce(a.col6, b.col7) as col6
from tableA a full outer join
     tableB b
     on 0 = 1;
```

However, I'm not sure if the preceding will work on the `temp` column.  One reason is that the `cast()` doesn't seem to be fully formulated:

Comment: When I do a Union All and key column for both tables is non-nullable, it still reports the view columns as nullable.  This makes it impossible to bring into Entity Framework. I gave your coalesce a shot, but its the same deal.  Really wish there was a way for to specify that a column of a view that its not nullable, regardless of what Oracle thinks.

Comment: @DavidP . . . I have no idea what your comment has to do with this answer.  If you have a question, though, feel free to ask one as a question.

Comment: I did post a question. Just no answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423920/import-oracle-union-all-view-into-entity-framework-edmx

Answer (score 1):

You could store the results of every query in a (temporary) result table and then in the end fetch all the results at once.

The only reason I can think of to do this is to split the work into smaller chunks either to conserve resources (not sure it will make that much of a difference though) or to benchmark the different queries separately.

Below how this would look more or less in Oracle. (I'm more of a MSSQL man)

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MyWorkingTable
   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
   AS Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
      from tableA
     WHERE 1 = 2

INSERT MyWorkingTable (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, temp, col6)
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
      from tableA;


INSERT MyWorkingTable (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, temp, col6)
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
      from tableB;

INSERT MyWorkingTable (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, temp, col6)
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
      from tableC;


-- etc

SELECT * FROM MyWorkingTable;
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of what you mean. Thanks

Comment: I probably know less about oracle syntax than you do =) But the idea is that you 1) create a working table with the layout of the required results. 2) run each query sequentially redirecting the output into this working table 3) select the contents of the working table. I'll see if I can get something similar going in SqlFiddle and edit it into my answer...